# Stop MediaPlayer when Fragment closes

Tags: android, fragment, android-mediaplayer

I am using a MediaPlayer inside a Fragment, I have managed to stop the music from playing, whenever the current fragment is changed.

But the problem is that, if I was within the fragment, and I press the back button to close the application, the music keeps streaming.

My code is the following:

```
@Override

public void setUserVisibleHint (boolean isVisibleToUser){


super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

If (this.isVisible ()){

If (!isVisibleToUser){

sound.stop ();

}else {

sound.start ();

}

}

}

sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity

(), R.raw.music);
```

How can I stop the music from playing, when I exit the application?

Comment: how many fragments you have in your activity

Comment: @krishna I have 3 fragments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stop your MediaPlayer from streaming in [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) method of the fragment.

This will stop the mediaplayer when you open the other fragment or you destroy the fragment